# Variation in benchmarking Drupal with standard bartik theme

Tags: firefox, drupal, firebug, benchmarking, page-load-time

I am benchmarking a default Drupal 7.28 installation with no extra modules or themes. And I am curious why I get slightly different results using Firebug considering everything is local. Here are some results I get in milliseconds:

```
394
385
389
459
440
381
```

Does anyone know why the page load time varies locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Benchmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_%28computing%29) normally don't always give the exact same results when they are run multiple times.

The page load time is not only influenced by the network speed. The results are also influenced by [multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) or dynamic compilation optimizations.

The (local) server doesn't always return the response at exactly the same time as it needs to process the request while it's running in concurrency with other programs. The same counts for your browser.

Multitasking assigns different time slices to your program to simulate that the programs run in parallel, though they actually run in sequence. And these time slices are managed by the underlying OS and may vary.

Also the server as well as the browser may do some compilation/execution optimizations when a request is run multiple times in sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your time, Could you please also clarify the difference in firebug between time and "onload time"

Comment: The "onload" time displayed in the summary at the bottom of the *Net* panel is the time when the ["onload" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) is fired. There's a tooltip with a small explanation of this when you hover the summary and a more detailed one inside the [*Net* panel description](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Request_Timeline). Can you please clarify, which other time you're talking about?